# Add PDFs together in Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, arrays

I am using [an api](http://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xir2/ws/en/index.html) which allows me to generate reports in PDF format. From the api I get the PDF in a `byte[]`. I send the reports to users via e-mail. Sometimes users will get one report, but in many cases they'll get many reports.

**I'm wondering** whether it's possible to take the bytes for more than one pdf and combine them in some way with another (or many) report(s) so I only send the user one pdf rather than 3 or 4. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When calling the API, can you call them with the content from the two reports combined? That way you will get one PDF

Comment: I would prefer something that doesn't require a license, but [iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php) looks cool. Thanks for the tip

Comment: [Older versions](https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0/downloads) of iText are licensed under the LGPL.

Comment: You can join PDFs using GhostScript, I believe ([try this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=merge+pdf+ghostscript)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, concatenating the bytestream will not work (read the standard ;-). You need to use something like [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to create a new PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend IText for generating and manipulating pdfs in Java. But even if you want to use your orginal package to generate the pdf, you can still use IText to merge all your pdfs together into 1 big pdf, as explained here: [iText Merge PDF with cropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646443/itext-merge-pdf-with-cropbox)